# unable to solve the task properly

Tags: java

I am using eclipse as an Ide. I tried to do the source code for the following task:

> "Write an algorithm to prompt the user to enter a series of integers (each on a separate line). The input is to be terminated with the value zero. Once the user has entered zero, display the number (count) of negative and positive values.":

This is my source code if anyone have any ideas or suggestions I would be gratefull to hear them.Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class CountNums {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);        
        System.out.println("Enter a series of integers and 0 for exit of the loop:");       
        int i = input.nextInt();        
        int negative = 0;       
        int positive = 0 ;          
        while (i != 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Enter next integer: ");
            i = input.nextInt();        
            if (i < 0) {
                System.out.println( negative += 1 );
            }else if (i > 0)  {
                System.out.println(positive += 1);          
            }
        }   
    } 

}
```

Comment: it sounds like a homerwork. policies of the website says we should not answer to that!

Comment: @Stefano you can answer in terms of giving hints, it's just not best practice to give the answer outright...

Comment: What's your problem with that?

Comment: maybe it sounds like but it isn't

Comment: well when yuo enter e series of nubmers e.g  1 , 5 , 8, 9 it starts to count the number while you are still entering numbers buti don't know how to get the count in the end for the positive and negative values.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Well,I am trying to program on java and I am following one book, so this is part of the book where there is a exercises but there is no answeres , so does this sound like homework ?

Comment: @Kiril: so it's an exercise that is not homework. Fair enough. It should be treated the same way as homework, however: We should provide hints and guidance instead of ready-made solutions.

Comment: Well As I said I would be gratefull for ideas or suggestions,I don't need the full source code.Nevermind.Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: -1 for not describing what you are asking for. Does your code compile? What problems are you having? Do ask questions, but be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. The first number that the user inputs is ignored in the count.  Why?
2. When the program ends, the variables `positive` and `negative` are not displayed as requested in the specs.  Instead, they are displayed EVERY TIME the user enters a number, except for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I won't provide written code for you, but i will provide hopefully something to help get you thinking.

The problem that you're asking for is not too difficult, so you should be able to get it with a little more thought.

You seem to be on the right track. The description says you want to print out the number of positive and negative numbers entered AFTER the user inputs 0. At the moment you're outputting it after every user input. <- Think about this a bit, and where you should be putting your output.

You're also asking for the nextInt() once outside your while loop. Try trace through the program as you enter a number in, and see what happens. You should fine that you are actually entering 2 integers before the if statements below are called.

P.S. You might want to make sure the formatting of your code is decent in the future...

EDIT: A little more help:

```
System.out.println( negative += 1 );
```

Currently does two things, its increasing your counter for the number of negative integers so far, and printing that value out.

You're correct that you want to keep incrementing that value every time the while loop is run (and a user puts in a number < 0), but what you don't want to do is print it at that stage of the program as well. Consider breaking that bit of code up into two, and placing the appropriate part in the appropriate location :)

So, think about:

How to increment a variable by itself, and how to print that variable by itself. Of course, change this for the positive line too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do System.out.println()... everytime you read in a number. Just increment the count (positive++) and do the System.out.println("Positive number count is " + positive); after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You print the number of negative or positive values in *each iteration*. You want to print that **after** the `while` loop instead.